javascript file reader urls are absurd am i suposted to store all of that in a db?
i want to give the user the download url once they have bought the images and here's my code :
  const get_file_url = (file: File) => {
    return new Promise((acc, err) => {
      const reader = new FileReader()
      reader.onload = (event) => {
        acc(event.target?.result)
      }
      reader.onerror = (error) => {
        err(error)
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    })
  }

you just pass it a file and it creates the url fine right, No the urls are huge (mK4EFLV700MChmzwBsU+9yyY8n86Lu'... 36363 more characters) around 35k character per image, and i don't think i should be storing allat in a db i don't even think i could if i wanted what do i do ?
Expected: a much shorter url

A better approach would be to store the images on a server and generate short, unique URLs that point to them.

Check the size of an image file on your own computer, and then think about how the contents of the file could be made any smaller. Image files are almost always already compressed.

The readAsDataURL function includes the file data encoded in base 64 in the URL that it returns:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL
As you note, that is probably not what you want. How you offer the user a URL to a file will depend on what storage mechanism is actually used for the files: filesystem, database, etc. Is the argument to get_file_url namely (file: File) accessible by a URL already? Or is it stored in a non-publicly-accessible location?
Whether it's on the filesystem in an obscure but public location, in a non-public location, or in a database, you could write a protected server route at a short, parameterized URL that maps some hash ID to the file path/database BLOB. Then, after authorization and lookup of the file path by hash or by query, serve the file as an HTTP response with appropriate headers.

yeah my bad am stupid i just forgot i had all the uploaded files in the file system and there was no need for all of this lol, all though this would have worked if i needed a shorter url i wouldve used bitly's api or something
